# EJB,JAX-WS support by Spring tcServer

Tags: spring, tomcat, tcserver

I see `tcServer` is built on `Apache Tomcat`. So the support of `EJB,JAX_W`S support is not available on tcServer/ApacheTomcat. But Apacahe Tomcat has other versions like `TomEE+` or integrating OpenEJB, provides support for EJB,JAX-WS.

So, is there similar support by tcServer to support EJB,JAX-WS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Like you said tc Server is based on Apache Tomcat, not TomEE. So, there is no support for EJB or JAX-WS, nor is there an effort to support EJB or JAX-WS.

Comment: Thank you Jason. That sums up my answer. But I wonder why there was no effort for that extra step.